# How to access VueJS Mixin within imported JS Library

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-mixin

I have a 'commonLibrary.js' which I've imported into my Vue app.

A small snippet of this library (and a good example) is:

```html
var defaultDecimalRounding=3

function formatNumber(number) {
    if (isNaN(number.value) == true) { return '-' }
    return numberWithCommas(parseFloat(number.value, 2).toFixed(defaultDecimalRounding));
}
```

So whenver "formatNumber" is called, it returns a number to a decimal rounding, based on the variable "defaultDecimalRounding"

What I'd like to do is move this defaultDecimalRounding variable out of the commonLibrary.js and into my Vue App so it can be changed within the app.

I've created a Mixin, as follows:

```html
Vue.mixin({
    data: function () {
        return {
            get defaultDecimalRounding() { return 3 },
        }
    },
});
```

But I can't seem to get my formatNumber function to read this defaultDecimalRounding Mixin.

I don't mind doing a code-rewrite for the commonLibrary.js, there's only a dozen or so functions in there, but it would be nice to know how to get VueJS and an imported JS library talking to each other for future projects.

*edit*
commonLibrary.js is imported as:

```
import common from './scripts/common.js';
const commonLibrary = {
    install() {
        Vue.common = common
        Vue.prototype.$common = common
    }
}
Vue.use(commonLibrary)
```

Comment: how do you import  and use `commonLibrary.js` ? show me the code

Answer (score 1):

Do as following:

in common.js

```
var defaultDecimalRounding = 3;

// use another name for export cause previous name  already is declared
export const defaultDecimal = defaultDecimalRounding;

function formatNumber(number) {
    if (isNaN(number.value) == true) { return '-' }
    return numberWithCommas(parseFloat(number.value, 2).toFixed(defaultDecimalRounding));
}
```

in your vue app:

```
import { defaultDecimal } from "./common";

Vue.mixin({
  data: function() {
    return {
      defaultDecimal : defaultDecimal
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Unfortunately it's done absolutely nothing.  Sure I can now see "defaultDecimal" on my Mixin now, but changing it isn't having any effect on the results returned.

Comment: Ah, you are right :). I believe you have to use a global state for that purpose OR vuex. take a look at this:  https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to use `this` because `defaultDecimalRounding` is now defined in the Vue instance. So something like `this.defaultDecimalRounding`

Comment: Tried that, get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaultDecimalRounding' of undefined" error